# Latex syntax for centering a figure or table

Tags: floats

I am trying to make the following figure appear in center of the page.But each code I use result in the figure appearing at the top of the page and caption at the bottom. Please what can I do. These are the latex code I used.

```
\clearpage

\newpage

\begin{figure}[b]

\includegraphics [ width=6in ,height=5in ]{figuretwo.pdf}

\caption{Interaction effect obtain from augmentation of $2^3$ design (12-run PB design)}

\end{figure}
```

Comment: Do you want to have it on an own page each time?

Comment: do not specify both height and width or you will distort the figure. My guess is that the figuretwo.pdf has white space within the image. you can crop with pdfcrop, or an pdff editor or using the viewbox options in `\includegraphics`. You can check by adding `\fbox` , so: `\fbox{\includegraphics [ width=6in ]{figuretwo.pdf}}` should not have a lot of space inside the box.

Answer (score 3):

Some suggestions:

- Make sure the text block is at least as wide as the desired width of the image
- Use `\centering` for horizontal centering
- Use the `[p]` placement specifier to place the image, vertically centered, on page

Incorporating these suggestions leads to the following MWE (minimum working example):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=0.5in, % set page parameters
    showframe]{geometry}    % omit 'showframe' option in real document
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % omit 'demo' option in real document
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[p] % <--- vertical centering on page
\centering        % <--- horizontal centering in text block
\includegraphics[width=6in, height=5in, 
             keepaspectratio]{figuretwo}

\caption{Interaction effect obtain from augmentation 
    of $2^3$ design (12-run PB design)}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```